# booktabs: What is the difference between \toprule and \hline

Tags: tables, booktabs

The horizontal lines in `tabular` environment can be constructed. What is the difference between `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\bottomrule` and specifying horizontal line using `\hline`?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

#### Short answer.

`\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` are improved versions of `\hline`; the standard `\hline` behaves (roughly) the same whether it is placed at the top, at the bottom or in the middle of a table. The improved versions `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` are thicker (in fact, `\midrule` is also slightly thicker) and they handle vertical spaces around them in a better way. As the documentation of booktabs states:

> The routines described below are to enable the easy production of
>   tables such as should appear in published scientific books and
>   journals. What distinguishes these from plain LaTeX tables is the
>   default use of additional space above and below rules, and rules of
>   varying ‘thickness’.

#### Not so short answer.

Lines produced with `\hline` have a default width controlled by `\arrayrulewidth` which is set (by the standard classes) to `0.4pt`. If you want to change the thickness, you need to set a different value for `\arrayrulewidth`.

On the other side, `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` have a default thicknes controlled by `\heavyrulewidth` which is set to `0.08em` by default; the default thicknes for `\midrule` is given by the length `\lightrulewidth`, with an initial value of `0.05em`. So, by default, `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` are approximately twice as thick as a line drawn with `\hline` and `\midrule` is slightly thicker than a line produced with `\hline`.

Additionally, `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` have an optional argument

```
\toprule[<length>]
\bottomrule[<length>]
\middlerule[<length>]
```

allowing to easily modify their thickness.

The lines defined by `booktabs` also have a special management of the space below and above them; this space is controlled by the following lengths:

1. For `\toprule`: the space above is given by `\abovetopsep` (set to `0pt` by default); the space below is given by `\belowrulesep` (default `0.65ex`).
2. For `\bottomrule`: the space above is given by `\aboverulesep` (set to `0.4ex` by default) and the space below is given by `\belowbottomsep` (default `0pt`).
3. For `\midrule`, the space above is controlled by `\aboverulesep` and the space below is given by `\belowrulesep`.

The fact that the length parameters `\heavyrulewidth`, `\lightrulewidth`, and `\cmidrulewidth` are specified in fractions of `em`, and the spaces above and below the rules are given in fracions of `ex`, is very nice, typographically speaking, because the rule widths and their spacing increase automatically if the default font size is changed from `10pt` to `11pt` or `12pt`. E.g., `\heavyrulewidth` is `.8pt`, `.876pt`, and `.94pt`, respectively, for default font sizes of `10pt`, `11pt`, and `12pt`. This is a major difference to `\hline`, which equals `0.4pt` by default regardless of the default font size.

The `booktabs` package also offers `\cmidrule` which is an improved version of the standard LaTeX `\cline` command designed to draw a sub-rule to extend over only some of the columns.

One of the disadvantages of the standard `\cline` command is that it draws a rule that extends to the full width of the columns specified in the argument, so two consecutive `\clines` will crash into each other (unless, for example, extra precaution is taken with `\extracolsep`). To easily prevent this crash, the improved `\cmidrule` offers optional trimming specifications; these specifications go in parentheses with no spaces separating them. The possible specifications are `r`, `r{<length>}`, `l` and `l{<length>}` (or any combination of these), where `r` and `l` indicate whether the right and/or left ends of the rule should be trimmed. The forms without explicit argument are equivalent to `r{\cmidrulekern}` and `l{\cmidrulekern}`, where
`\cmidrulekern` defaults to `0.5em`.For example,

```
\cmidrule(lr{.75em}){1-3}
```

gives a rule extending from column one to column three with a default left trim of `0.5em` and `0.75em` right trim.

`\cmidrule` has also an optional argument to change the thickness; the complete syntax is

```
\cmidrule[<length>](<trimming>){a–b}
```

The default value for `<length>`  is `\cmidrulewidth` (`0.03em`); the last argument 
gives the column numbers to be spanned.

Even with simple tables you can see the difference between the results obtained using the default LaTeX `\hline` and the rules produced with the help of `booktabs`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{*{3}{c}}
\hline
Header1 & Header 2 & Header3 \\
\hline
Column1a & Column2a & Column3a \\
Column1b & Column2b & Column3b \\
Column1c & Column2c & Column3c \\
Column1d & Column2d & Column3d \\
\hline
\end{tabular}\quad
\begin{tabular}{*{3}{c}}
\toprule
Header1 & Header 2 & Header3 \\
\midrule
Column1a & Column2a & Column3a \\
Column1b & Column2b & Column3b \\
Column1c & Column2c & Column3c \\
Column1d & Column2d & Column3d \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One can also trim them from either left or right with `\cmidrule`.

Comment: I would move the picture from the end nearer to the top in the "short answer". I actually think the picture is the shortest answer there is!

Comment: Is it also possible to specify the length of the rules? I need a midrule of length 7.34 cm, say.