# How to make \hline in table print fainter

Tags: tables, rules, booktabs

I have following code. 
I need to print the \hline fainter than normal so that it does not interfere with writting (if dotted, better). Kindly help

```
\section*{\textrecipe}
\renewcommand\baselinestretch{3.5}\selectfont
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{0.5cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{3cm}|p{2cm}|p{3cm}}
\toprule
Sr & Drug & Dose & Frequency & Duration & Remark \\ \midrule
 1  &      &      &           &          &        \\ \hline
 2  &      &      &           &          &        \\ \hline
 3  &      &      &           &          &        \\ \hline
 4  &      &      &           &          &        \\  \hline 
 5  &      &      &           &          &        \\ \hline 
 6  &      &      &           &          &        \\ \hline 
 7  &      &      &           &          &        \\   \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.5}\selectfont
```

Comment: Best would be to set the width to 0pt. Shortcut: Remove all `\hline`s .

Comment: Out of interest, why no minimal working example? Why using a float without letting it float?

Comment: You can add some vertical padding around `\hline`s with the `cellspace` or `makecell` packages.

Comment: [What is the difference between toprule and hline?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156122/booktabs-what-is-the-difference-between-toprule-and-hline): *Lines produced with \hline have a default width controlled by \arrayrulewidth which is set (by the standard classes) to 0.4pt. If you want to change the thickness, you need to set a different value for \arrayrulewidth.* Doesn't that answer your question? And the linked earler question?

Comment: I understand this is a table to be hand-filled, so the need of guide-line.: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10243/table-border-options

Comment: Is not a good idea a `\hline` with  less of 0.4pt. Instead,  The easiest and elegant way is simply  not use at all  `\hline` in the inner rows and stay only with the  `booktabs` rules, but note that this package allow also special rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If removing the `\hline`s all together and using `booktabs` is not sufficient, a dotted lines version using the `arydshln` package may help:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\setlength{\dashlinedash}{.4pt}
\setlength{\dashlinegap}{.8pt}

\begin{document}
\section*{textrecipe}
\renewcommand\baselinestretch{3}
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{0.5cm}:p{2cm}:p{2cm}:p{3cm}:p{2cm}:p{3cm}}
\hdashline
Sr  & Drug & Dose & Frequency & Duration & Remark \\ \hdashline
 1  &      &      &           &          &        \\ \hdashline
 2  &      &      &           &          &        \\ \hdashline
 3  &      &      &           &          &        \\ \hdashline
 4  &      &      &           &          &        \\ \hdashline 
 5  &      &      &           &          &        \\ \hdashline 
 6  &      &      &           &          &        \\ \hdashline 
 7  &      &      &           &          &        \\ \hdashline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.5}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I can propose this, using grey lines rather than dashed lines. The lines won't inerfere with the contents,as I use `cellspace` to obtain some padding between rows. I also use `booktabs` for it is easy to have variable thickness lines, and it accepts colouring lines.

The cellspace package allows to define a `minimal` vertical spacing at the top and at the bottom of cells in columns with specifiers prefixed with the letter `S` (or `C` if you load `siunitx`). Paragraph-type specifiers have to be enclosed within `{}`. It works fine in most cases.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs, cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{8pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{8pt}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X}

\begin{document}
\section*{textrecipe}
\begin{table}[! htb]
  \centering\setlength\aboverulesep{0pt}\setlength\belowrulesep{0pt}
  \arrayrulecolor{Gainsboro}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{!{\color{Gainsboro}\vrule width 1.5pt}Sc!{\color{Gainsboro}\vrule width 1.5pt}>{\hsize=0.84\hsize}S{X}|>{\hsize=0.84\hsize}X|>{\hsize=1.24\hsize}X| >{\hsize=0.84\hsize}X|>{\hsize=1.24\hsize}X!{\color{Gainsboro}\vrule width 1.5pt}}
    \midrule[1.5pt]
    Sr & Drug & Dose & Frequency & Duration & Remark \\ \midrule[1.5pt]
    1 & & & & & \\ \midrule
    2 & & & & & \\ \midrule
    3 & & & & & \\ \midrule
    4 & & & & & \\ \midrule
    5 & & & & & \\ \midrule
    6 & & & & & \\ \midrule
    7 & & & & & \\ \bottomrule[1.5pt]
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a `tikz` solution. It gives you a **lot** of flexibility:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    ]
    \matrix (m) [ matrix of nodes,nodes in empty cells, 
        every node/.append style={align=left}, 
        nodes = {
            %red, 
            %draw, 
            anchor=center, % https://www.wikiloc.com/wikiloc/view.do?id=16476493
            minimum height=1cm, 
            minimum width=2cm, 
            inner sep=0pt,
        },    
        column 6/.append style={nodes={minimum width=8cm}, },
    ]
    {
        Sr  & Drug & Dose & Frequency & Duration &Remark \\ 
        1  &      &      &           &          &        \\ 
        2  &      &      &           &          &        \\ 
        3  &      &      &           &          &        \\ 
        4  &      &      &           &          &        \\ 
        5  &      &      &           &          &        \\ 
        6  &      &      &           &          &        \\ 
        7  &      &      &           &          &        \\ 
    };

    % vertical lines 
    \foreach \c in {1,...,6} 
    \draw [gray] (m-1-\c.north east) --  (m-8-\c.south east);

    % horizontal continous lines
    \draw[gray] (m-1-1.north west) -- (m-1-6.north east);
    \draw[gray] (m-1-1.south west) -- (m-1-6.south east);
    \draw[gray] (m-8-1.south west) -- (m-8-6.south east);

    % horizontal dotted lines
    \foreach \r in {2,...,7} 
    \draw [dotted, blue] (m-\r-1.south west) --  (m-\r-6.south east);


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output...]

Answer (score 1):

You can change the setting for `\arrayrulewidth`.

Note you don't need to set `\baselinestretch`, but `\arraystretch`. Also `table` is useless in this context; just `center` is what you need. Since `\arraystretch` and `\arrayrulewidth` are set in a group, their value will be restored at the end of `center`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}

\section*{\textrecipe}
\begin{center}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{3.5}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.1pt}

\begin{tabular}{p{0.5cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{3cm}|p{2cm}|p{3cm}}
\hline
Sr  & Drug & Dose & Frequency & Duration & Remark \\ \hline
 1  &      &      &           &          &        \\ \hline
 2  &      &      &           &          &        \\ \hline
 3  &      &      &           &          &        \\ \hline
 4  &      &      &           &          &        \\ \hline
 5  &      &      &           &          &        \\ \hline
 6  &      &      &           &          &        \\ \hline
 7  &      &      &           &          &        \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The picture is partial; showing the whole picture it would show artifacts due to screen resolution.

[image]