# matrix problem in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

Can anyone explain why this simple table comes out skewed?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    ]
    \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells,
        nodes = {minimum width=1cm,},    
        column 4/.style={minimum width=8cm},
    ]
    {
        Sr  & Drug & Dose & Frequency & Duration & Remark \\ 
        1  &      &      &           &          &        \\ 
        2  &      &      &           &          &        \\ 
        3  &      &      &           &          &        \\ 
        4  &      &      &           &          &        \\ 
        5  &      &      &           &          &        \\ 
        6  &      &      &           &          &        \\ 
        7  &      &      &           &          &        \\ 
    };

    \foreach \c in {1,...,6} 
    \draw [gray] (m-1-\c.north east) --  (m-8-\c.south east);

    \draw (m-1-1.south west) -- (m-1-6.south east);
    \draw (m-8-1.south west) -- (m-8-6.south east);

    \foreach \r in {2,...,7} 
    \draw [dotted, blue] (m-\r-1.south west) --  (m-\r-6.south east);


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can for coordinates for  vertical lines consider east sides of nodes in the first row. With this approach you not need to define node widths (assuming, that the nodes in the first row are the widest):

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells,
    nodes = {minimum width=1cm,minimum height=1ex,text depth=0.25ex},
%        column 4/.style={minimum width=8cm},
]
{
    Sr  & Drug & Dose & Frequency & Duration & Remark \\
    1  &      &      &           &          &        \\
    2  &      &      &           &          &        \\
    3  &      &      &           &          &        \\
    4  &      &      &           &          &        \\
    5  &      &      &           &          &        \\
    6  &      &      &           &          &        \\
    7  &      &      &           &          &        \\
};

\foreach \c in {1,...,6}
\draw [gray] (m-1-\c.north east) --  (m-1-\c.north east |- m-8-1.south);

\draw (m-1-1.south west) -- (m-1-6.south east);
\draw (m-8-1.south west) -- (m-8-6.south east -| m-1-6.east);

\foreach \r in {2,...,7}
\draw [dotted, blue] (m-\r-1.south west) --  (m-\r-1.south west -| m-1-6.east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
In case that you like to define minimum width to all nodes, but different in some column, than you can define the most used width in nodes style definition, and exceptional with, for example `column 6/.style={nodes={minimum width=8cm}` (for column 6) as you noted in your comment below. In this case is not need to define vertical lines in respect to nodes width in the first row. An example of the such solution is:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm, preview]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells,
    nodes = {minimum width=22mm, inner xsep=2mm, minimum height=1ex,text depth=0.25ex},
    column 1/.style={nodes={minimum width= 8mm}},
    column 6/.style={nodes={minimum width=88mm}}
            ]
{
    Sr 
        & Drug 
            & Dose 
                & Frequency 
                    & Duration 
                        & Remark \\
    1   &   &   &   &   &        \\
    2   &   &   &   &   &        \\
    3   &   &   &   &   &        \\
    4   &   &   &   &   &        \\
    5   &   &   &   &   &        \\
    6   &   &   &   &   &        \\
    7   &   &   &   &   &        \\
};

\draw [gray] (m-1-1.north west) --  (m-8-1.south west);
\foreach \c in {1,...,6}
\draw [gray] (m-1-\c.north east) --  (m-8-\c.south east);

\draw (m-1-1.north west) -- (m-1-6.north east);
\draw (m-1-1.south west) -- (m-1-6.south east);
\draw (m-8-1.south west) -- (m-8-6.south east);

\foreach \r in {2,...,7}
\draw [dotted, blue] (m-\r-1.south west) --  (m-\r-6.south east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is nIce. But I really want to specify a wider column, independently from the first line text....

Comment: Found it. You have to use `column 6/.style={nodes={minimum width=8cm},`.

Comment: I wonder, what is purpose of your matrix. It seems, that simple tabular environment would better fulfill your requirements.

Comment: It was just an exercise --- I am trying to better understand `matrix`. I used it to propose a kind of "form" in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354463/how-to-make-hline-in-table-print-fainter

Answer (score 1):

The empty nodes are created with a `minimum width` of 1 cm, as you request. But the title *Frequency* is larger than that.

Change to `nodes = {minimum width=2cm,}` in order to see the difference.

The setting `column 4/.style={minimum width=8cm}` does not have any effect, as the column itself does not have a width. However, you could say `column 4/.style={text width=8cm}` to achieve what you initially wanted.

Comment: yes, but I am saying that nodes in column 4 has 8cm minimum width...

Comment: see updated answer :)

Comment: Yep - I see. So how can I have a column wider than the others?

Comment: I was wrong saying that the style did not have any effect. Answer updated (again). I should have checked more thoroughly.