# Framing cells vertically in a table

Tags: tables, framed, tabularx

I want to add a box in a tabularx table that would frame several cells vertically. There is this post that shows how to frame cells horizontally ([Framing cells in a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4676/framing-cells-in-a-table)), but I cannot figure out how to do to have the box extend over several rows. Here is what I would roughly like to get (but with a nice box):

```
Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3
                      +-----+
bla      & bla      & |bla  |
                      |     |
bla      & bla      & |bla  |
                      +-----+
```

Any idea of how I could do that?

Edit: the solutions proposed below are very nice. But they are compatible with the tabular environment only, it seems, and not with tabularx and booktabs. Below is the code I have used. Does anyone have an idea of how to extend these solutions to the tabularx style? If not, then I will just rewrite all my tables using the simple tabular style.

```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{tabularx, booktabs}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{calc}

   \newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
   \newcommand{\DrawBox}[1][]{%
        \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{
        \draw[black,#1]
           ($(left)+(-0.5em,2.0ex)$) rectangle
           ($(right)+(0.75em,-0.75ex)$);}
          }

   \begin{document}
   \begin{table}[H]
   \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{0.3\textwidth}{Y*{4}{c}}
        \toprule
         & Masc  & Fem & Neut\\ 
        \midrule  \cline{4-4}
        Nom & hic & haec & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{hoc} \\ 
        Acc & hunc & hanc & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{hoc} \\ \cline{4-4}
        \bottomrule 
    \end{tabularx} 
   \end{table}
     \begin{table}[H]
   \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{0.3\textwidth}{Y*{4}{c}}
        \toprule
         & Masc  & Fem & Neut\\ 
        \midrule  
        Nom & hic & haec & \tikzmark{left}hoc \\ 
        Acc & hunc & hanc & hoc\tikzmark{right} \\ 
        \bottomrule 
    \end{tabularx} 
     \end{table}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Please always provide a complete test document, but you can do the horizontal parts with `\cline` and the vertical parts with `|`

Comment: Both solutions are compatible with `tabularx`. Show a complete MWE that is not working.

Comment: You are noy using `\DrawBox` in your second code, so the box is not drawn. Add `\DrawBox` just before `\end{table}`.

Comment: Have updated solution which provides for a more flexible `\DrawBox` macro (using `booktabs`), along with some usage notes. This will work just a well with `tabularx`.

Comment: See also the thread [Highlighting table cells](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4850/highlighting-table-cells/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{*6{c}}\hline
    Col 1 & Col 2 & Col 3 & Col 4 & Col 5 & Col 6 \\\cline{1-1}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{bla}   & bla   & bla   & bla   & bla   & bla \\
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{bla}   & bla   & bla   & bla   & bla   & bla \\ 
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{ble} & ble & ble & bla & bla & bla \\ \cline{1-1}
    bla   & bla   & bla   & bla   & bla   & bla \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `tabularx` and `booktabs`:

```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{tabularx, booktabs}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{table}[H]
   \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{0.4\textwidth}{X*{4}{c}}      %% 0.3\textwidth too narrow 
                                                   %% and Y column type not known
        \toprule
         & Masc  & Fem & Neut\\
        \midrule  \cline{4-4}
        Nom & hic & haec & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{hoc} \\
        Acc & hunc & hanc & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{hoc} \\ \cline{4-4}
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
   \end{table}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 20):

There is always the `tikz` solution. Here is one that use bascially the same code from
[Highlight elements in the matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40059/4301) but with a more flexible `\DrawBox` macro. And since it is `tikz` you get all the additional flexibility that comes with that:

[image]

### Usage:

1. You use `\tikzmark{<name>}` to "mark" a particular location with `<name>`.
2. These named locations are passed to the `\DrawMacro` which uses these are the boundary of the drawing.  You need one `\DrawBox` call for *each* box that you wish to draw.

### Note:

- This does require two runs. First one to determine the locations, and the second to do the drawing.
- The `\tikzmark` is from [Adding a large brace next to a body of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/adding-a-large-brace-next-to-a-body-of-text/1570#1570).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\newcommand{\DrawBox}[3][]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{
    \draw[black,#1]
      ($(#2)+(-0.5em,2.0ex)$) rectangle
      ($(#3)+(0.75em,-0.75ex)$);}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{*{7}{c}}\toprule
    Col 1 &  Col 2                   &       Col  3                 & Col 4                   & Col 5 & Col 6                         & Col 7 \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-6}
     0    &   1                      & \tikzmark{top left 1}abcd    &   0                     &   0   &   0                           &   1   \\
     1    &   \tikzmark{top left 3}0 & www                          &   0                     &   0   &   0                           &   1   \\
     0    &   1                      & xyz\tikzmark{bottom right 1} &  \tikzmark{top left 2}1 &   0   &   0                           &   0   \\
     0    &   0                      & 1                            &   0                     &   0   &   0\tikzmark{bottom right 3}  &   0   \\
     0    &   0                      & 0                            &   0                     &   0   &   1                           &   0\tikzmark{bottom right 2} \\
     0    &   0                      & 1                            &   0                     &   0   &   0                           &   0 \\
     \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}

\DrawBox[ultra thick, red]{top left 1}{bottom right 1}
\DrawBox[ultra thick, blue]{top left 2}{bottom right 2}
\DrawBox[ultra thick, draw=green, dotted, fill=yellow!15, fill opacity=0.3]{top left 3}{bottom right 3}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you have a command `\Block` which can merge cells but which can also be used to draw a frame around a rectangle of cells.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ccc}
Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\
bla & bla & \Block[draw=red,rounded-corners]{2-1}{} bla \\
bla & bla & bla 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the first code]

If you prefer a frame adjusted to the contents of the cells, you can do that with Tikz in the `\CodeAfter` by using the PGF/Tikz nodes created by `nicematrix` under the cells, rows and columns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ccc}
Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\
bla & bla & bla \\
bla & bla & bla 
\CodeAfter 
  \tikz \node [draw=red,rounded corners,fit=(2-3)(3-3)] {} ; 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]