# Misplaced \omit in custom environment wrapping tabular

Tags: tikz-pgf, tabularx, draw

My goal was to easily frame a column of a tabular with a rectangle. I found a good answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/167913). So I tried to adapt it to my use case and that worked:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{slashbox}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\newcommand{\DrawBox}[3][]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{
        \draw[black,#1]
        ($(#2)+(-0.0em,0.5ex)$) rectangle
        ($(#3)+(0.75em,0.0ex)$);}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|ccccccc|}
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{}\tikzmark{c1}\\
    \hline
    \backslashbox{$v$}{$k$} 
    & 1        & 2    & 3    & 4    & 5        & 6    & 7      \\
    \hline
    1 & 7(1)    & 4 & - & - & -     & 5    & -  \\    
    2 & 7(4)    & -    & 2    & - & 6(4)    & - & 1  \\
    3 & -        & -    & -    & 3    & 6(3)    & -    & -     \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{}&\tikzmark{c2}\\
\end{tabular}
\DrawBox[ultra thick, black]{c1}{c2}

\end{document}
```

The result looks like I expected it to look:

[image: what it's supposed to look like]

But when I tried creating a custom environment (as I have to repeatedly use this trick) I get a weird error.

> Misplaced \omit. \end{tabularHighlighted}

When I place an ampersand or a newline in front of the multicolumn the error disappers but leaving the cell empty is no solution as the frame of the tabular will then be drawn around that cell.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{slashbox}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\newcommand{\DrawBox}[3][]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{
        \draw[black,#1]
        ($(#2)+(-0.0em,0.5ex)$) rectangle
        ($(#3)+(0.75em,0.0ex)$);}
}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{tabularHighlighted}{mm}
{
    \begin{tabular}{#1}
    \multicolumn{#2}{c}{}\tikzmark{c1}\\
}
{
    \multicolumn{#2}{c}{}&\tikzmark{c2}\\
    \end{tabular}
    \DrawBox[ultra thick, black]{c1}{c2}
}

\begin{document}


\begin{tabularHighlighted}{|l|ccccccc|}{3}
    \hline
    \backslashbox{$v$}{$k$} 
   & 1        & 2    & 3    & 4    & 5        & 6    & 7      \\
    \hline
    1 & 7(1)    & 4 & - & - & -     & 5    & -  \\    
    2 & 7(4)    & -    & 2    & - & 6(4)    & - & 1  \\
    3 & -        & -    & -    & 3    & 6(3)    & -    & -     \\
    \hline
\end{tabularHighlighted}

\end{document}
```

---

## Update

Here's the log with \listfiles for anyone wondering

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2015.4.18)  6 JUN 2017 13:07
entering extended mode
**template_Article2.tex
(template_Article2.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 68 languages loaded.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\basiclayer\pgf.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\utilities\pgfrcs.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-common.te
x"
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks14
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen103
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen104

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-common-li
sts.tex"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-latex.def
"
\pgfutil@abb=\box26
 ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ms\everyshi.sty"
Package: everyshi 2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfrcs.code.tex"
Package: pgfrcs 2013/12/20 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.28)
))
Package: pgf 2013/12/18 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.14)
 ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcore.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks15
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2014/10/28 v1.0p Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 91.

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pdftex-def\pdftex.def"
File: pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
\Gread@gobject=\count87
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen105
\Gin@req@width=\dimen106
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys.code.tex
"
Package: pgfsys 2013/11/30 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.47)
 ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex
"
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks16
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks17

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeysfiltered.c
ode.tex"
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks18
))
\pgf@x=\dimen107
\pgf@y=\dimen108
\pgf@xa=\dimen109
\pgf@ya=\dimen110
\pgf@xb=\dimen111
\pgf@yb=\dimen112
\pgf@xc=\dimen113
\pgf@yc=\dimen114
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read1
\c@pgf@counta=\count88
\c@pgf@countb=\count89
\c@pgf@countc=\count90
\c@pgf@countd=\count91
\t@pgf@toka=\toks19
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks20
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks21

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgf.cfg"
File: pgf.cfg 2008/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-pdftex.def

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys-pdftex.d
ef"
File: pgfsys-pdftex.def 2013/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.33)

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys-common-p
df.def"
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2013/10/10  (rcs-revision 1.13)
)))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsyssoftpath.
code.tex"
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count92
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count93
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsysprotocol.
code.tex"
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
)) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xcolor\xcolor.sty"
Package: xcolor 2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\color.cfg"
File: color.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1337.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1341.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1353.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1355.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1356.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1357.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1358.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1359.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1360.
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcore.code.tex
"
Package: pgfcore 2010/04/11 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
 ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmath.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathcalc.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathutil.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathparser.code.tex
"
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen115
\pgfmath@count=\count94
\pgfmath@box=\box27
\pgfmath@toks=\toks22
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks23
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks24
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.code.
tex"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.basic
.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.trigo
nometric.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.rando
m.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.compa
rison.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.base.
code.tex")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.round
.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.misc.
code.tex")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.integ
erarithmetics.code.tex")))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfloat.code.tex"
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count95
))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepoints.co
de.tex"
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2013/10/07  (rcs-revision 1.27)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen116
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen117
\pgf@picminy=\dimen118
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen119
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen120
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen121
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen122
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen123
\pgf@xx=\dimen124
\pgf@xy=\dimen125
\pgf@yx=\dimen126
\pgf@yy=\dimen127
\pgf@zx=\dimen128
\pgf@zy=\dimen129
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepathconst
ruct.code.tex"
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2013/10/07  (rcs-revision 1.29)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen130
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen131
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepathusage
.code.tex"
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2013/12/13  (rcs-revision 1.23)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen132
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen133
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorescopes.co
de.tex"
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2013/10/09  (rcs-revision 1.44)
\pgfpic=\box28
\pgf@hbox=\box29
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box30
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count96
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoregraphicst
ate.code.tex"
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2013/09/19  (rcs-revision 1.11)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen134
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoretransform
ations.code.tex"
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2013/10/10  (rcs-revision 1.17)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen135
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen136
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen137
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorequick.cod
e.tex"
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2008/10/09  (rcs-revision 1.3)
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreobjects.c
ode.tex"
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2006/10/11  (rcs-revision 1.2)
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepathproce
ssing.code.tex"
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorearrows.co
de.tex"
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2013/11/07  (rcs-revision 1.40)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen138
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreshade.cod
e.tex"
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.15)
\pgf@max=\dimen139
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count97
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreimage.cod
e.tex"
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.18)

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreexternal.
code.tex"
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box31
))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorelayers.co
de.tex"
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2013/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoretranspare
ncy.code.tex"
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2013/09/30  (rcs-revision 1.5)
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepatterns.
code.tex"
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2013/11/07  (rcs-revision 1.5)
)))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\modules\pgfmoduleshapes.cod
e.tex"
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2013/10/31  (rcs-revision 1.34)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box32
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\modules\pgfmoduleplot.code.
tex"
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2013/07/31  (rcs-revision 1.12)
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\compatibility\pgfcomp-version
-0-65.sty"
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2007/07/03 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen140
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen141
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\compatibility\pgfcomp-version
-1-18.sty"
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2007/07/23 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.1)
))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\utilities\pgffor.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\utilities\pgfkeys.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex"
)) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\math\pgfmath.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmath.code.tex"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgffor.code.tex"
Package: pgffor 2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.25)

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmath.code.tex")
\pgffor@iter=\dimen142
\pgffor@skip=\dimen143
\pgffor@stack=\toks25
\pgffor@toks=\toks26
))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\tikz.cod
e.tex"
Package: tikz 2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.142)

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\libraries\pgflibraryplothan
dlers.code.tex"
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2013/08/31 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count98
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen144
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen145
\tikz@lasty=\dimen146
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen147
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen148
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen149
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen150
\tikz@figbox=\box33
\tikz@figbox@bg=\box34
\tikz@tempbox=\box35
\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box36
\tikztreelevel=\count99
\tikznumberofchildren=\count100
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count101
\tikz@fig@count=\count102

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\modules\pgfmodulematrix.cod
e.tex"
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2013/09/17  (rcs-revision 1.8)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count103
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count104
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count105
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count106

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\librarie
s\tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex"
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2008/06/17 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.2)
)))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3packages\xparse\xparse.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\expl3.sty"
Package: expl3 2015/03/01 v5547 L3 programming layer (loader) 

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\expl3-code.tex"
Package: expl3 2015/03/01 v5547 L3 programming layer (code) 
L3 Module: l3bootstrap 2015/02/28 v5542 L3 Bootstrap code

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\misc\etex.sty"
Package: etex 2015/03/02 v2.1 eTeX basic definition package (PEB,DPC)
\et@xins=\count107
)
L3 Module: l3names 2015/02/24 v5535 L3 Namespace for primitives
L3 Module: l3basics 2015/01/27 v5500 L3 Basic definitions
L3 Module: l3expan 2014/11/27 v5472 L3 Argument expansion
L3 Module: l3tl 2015/01/27 v5500 L3 Token lists
L3 Module: l3str 2015/03/01 v5545 L3 Strings
L3 Module: l3seq 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Sequences and stacks
L3 Module: l3int 2015/02/21 v5529 L3 Integers
\c_max_int=\count108
\l_tmpa_int=\count109
\l_tmpb_int=\count110
\g_tmpa_int=\count111
\g_tmpb_int=\count112
L3 Module: l3quark 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Quarks
L3 Module: l3prg 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Control structures
\g__prg_map_int=\count113
L3 Module: l3clist 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Comma separated lists
L3 Module: l3token 2014/09/15 v5422 L3 Experimental token manipulation
L3 Module: l3prop 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Property lists
L3 Module: l3msg 2015/02/26 v5537 L3 Messages
L3 Module: l3file 2014/08/24 v5369 L3 File and I/O operations
\l_iow_line_count_int=\count114
\l__iow_target_count_int=\count115
\l__iow_current_line_int=\count116
\l__iow_current_word_int=\count117
\l__iow_current_indentation_int=\count118
L3 Module: l3skip 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Dimensions and skips
\c_zero_dim=\dimen151
\c_max_dim=\dimen152
\l_tmpa_dim=\dimen153
\l_tmpb_dim=\dimen154
\g_tmpa_dim=\dimen155
\g_tmpb_dim=\dimen156
\c_zero_skip=\skip43
\c_max_skip=\skip44
\l_tmpa_skip=\skip45
\l_tmpb_skip=\skip46
\g_tmpa_skip=\skip47
\g_tmpb_skip=\skip48
\c_zero_muskip=\muskip10
\c_max_muskip=\muskip11
\l_tmpa_muskip=\muskip12
\l_tmpb_muskip=\muskip13
\g_tmpa_muskip=\muskip14
\g_tmpb_muskip=\muskip15
L3 Module: l3keys 2015/01/27 v5500 L3 Key-value interfaces
\g__keyval_level_int=\count119
\l_keys_choice_int=\count120
L3 Module: l3fp 2014/08/22 v5336 L3 Floating points
\c__fp_leading_shift_int=\count121
\c__fp_middle_shift_int=\count122
\c__fp_trailing_shift_int=\count123
\c__fp_big_leading_shift_int=\count124
\c__fp_big_middle_shift_int=\count125
\c__fp_big_trailing_shift_int=\count126
\c__fp_Bigg_leading_shift_int=\count127
\c__fp_Bigg_middle_shift_int=\count128
\c__fp_Bigg_trailing_shift_int=\count129
L3 Module: l3box 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Experimental boxes
\c_empty_box=\box37
\l_tmpa_box=\box38
\l_tmpb_box=\box39
\g_tmpa_box=\box40
\g_tmpb_box=\box41
L3 Module: l3coffins 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Coffin code layer
\l__coffin_internal_box=\box42
\l__coffin_internal_dim=\dimen157
\l__coffin_offset_x_dim=\dimen158
\l__coffin_offset_y_dim=\dimen159
\l__coffin_x_dim=\dimen160
\l__coffin_y_dim=\dimen161
\l__coffin_x_prime_dim=\dimen162
\l__coffin_y_prime_dim=\dimen163
\c_empty_coffin=\box43
\l__coffin_aligned_coffin=\box44
\l__coffin_aligned_internal_coffin=\box45
\l_tmpa_coffin=\box46
\l_tmpb_coffin=\box47
\l__coffin_display_coffin=\box48
\l__coffin_display_coord_coffin=\box49
\l__coffin_display_pole_coffin=\box50
\l__coffin_display_offset_dim=\dimen164
\l__coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen165
\l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen166
L3 Module: l3color 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Experimental color support
L3 Module: l3candidates 2015/03/01 v5544 L3 Experimental additions to l3kernel
\l__box_top_dim=\dimen167
\l__box_bottom_dim=\dimen168
\l__box_left_dim=\dimen169
\l__box_right_dim=\dimen170
\l__box_top_new_dim=\dimen171
\l__box_bottom_new_dim=\dimen172
\l__box_left_new_dim=\dimen173
\l__box_right_new_dim=\dimen174
\l__box_internal_box=\box51
\l__coffin_bounding_shift_dim=\dimen175
\l__coffin_left_corner_dim=\dimen176
\l__coffin_right_corner_dim=\dimen177
\l__coffin_bottom_corner_dim=\dimen178
\l__coffin_top_corner_dim=\dimen179
\l__coffin_scaled_total_height_dim=\dimen180
\l__coffin_scaled_width_dim=\dimen181
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3unicode-data.def"
File: l3unicode-data.def 2015/03/01 v5544 L3 Unicode data
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3pdfmode.def"
File: l3pdfmode.def 2015/03/01 v5544 L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
\l__driver_color_stack_int=\count130
))
Package: xparse 2014/11/25 v5471 L3 Experimental document command parser
\l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count131
\l__xparse_m_args_int=\count132
\l__xparse_mandatory_args_int=\count133
\l__xparse_processor_int=\count134
\l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count135
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\librarie
s\tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex"
File: tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex 2013/07/15 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.9)
)
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-environment"
. 
. Defining environment 'tabularHighlighted' with sig. 'mm' on line 24.
.................................................
 (template_Article2.aux)
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 26.

ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count136
\scratchdimen=\dimen182
\scratchbox=\box52
\nofMPsegments=\count137
\nofMParguments=\count138
\everyMPshowfont=\toks27
\MPscratchCnt=\count139
\MPscratchDim=\dimen183
\MPnumerator=\count140
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count141
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks28
)
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 29.

! Misplaced \omit.
\multispan ->\omit 
                   \@multispan 
l.38     \end{tabularHighlighted}

I expect to see \omit only after tab marks or the \cr of
an alignment. Proceed, and I'll ignore this case.
```

Comment: Which error do you get, if you remove `slashbox`?

Comment: I get no error from the posted example with texlive 2017 + slashbox.sty copied from ctan

Comment: @TeXnician exactly the same error :(

Comment: Try updating your TeX distro.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm using Miktex but does that really make a difference?

Comment: should not make a difference. add `\listfiles` to your preamble and show the file list from the end of the log (you would need to scroll past the error)  The error means you have something before `\multicolumn` when `\multicolumn` has to be the first thing in its cell,  so the other possibility is you have some invisible control character there.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Added the log, but I can't figure out what's wrong from that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was due to outdated software and was solved with an update.

Answer (score 0):

Weirdly I suddenly got an error message that miktex was missing some dll so I reinstalled miktex and now the error does not reappear.

Comment: you had very old packages eg expl3-code from 2015 but one on ctan was from this year, the updaye presumably gave you consistent set of packages