# Nested boxes around cells in a table

Tags: tables, framed

I would like to nest two boxes in my table. It looks like this:

```
 content      content      content      content      content
            +----------------------+
 content    | content      content |    content      content
            |+--------------------+|
 content    ||content      content||    content      content
            |+--------------------+|
 content    | content      content |    content      content
            +----------------------+
 content      content      content      content      content
```

I looked at [Framing cells in a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4676/framing-cells-in-a-table) which provides a good solution, but the main issue is that I can't set the length of the horizontal line in the inner box. `\cline{2-3}` always produces the same width. It would produce something that looks like this:

```
 content      content      content      content      content
            +----------------------+
 content    | content      content |    content      content
            ++--------------------++
 content    ||content      content||    content      content
            ++--------------------++
 content    | content      content |    content      content
            +----------------------+
 content      content      content      content      content
```

But I would like to avoid the inner box from intersecting with / joining the outer box.

Comment: You should rather show the code so far instead of a an ASCII-ART like image ;-)

Comment: Using `matrix` from TikZ is probably the simplest way to achieve this.

Answer (score 4):

For exercises and starting point:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,
               tikz,
               preview
               ]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,
                matrix,
                }

\begin{document}   
\begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style = {inner sep=0.5mm}
                    ]
\matrix (magic) [matrix of nodes,
                 column sep=1.5mm,
                 row sep=1.5mm]
{
content & content & content & content & content \\
content & content & content & content & content \\
content & content & content & content & content \\
content & content & content & content & content \\
content & content & content & content & content \\
};
\node (a) [draw, fit=(magic-3-2) (magic-3-3)] {};
\node (b) [draw, fit=(magic-2-2) (a) (magic-4-3)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

How to do this in your table? First you need to provide complete document with your table, that I can see, what can be done. Above image only replicate your image in question :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. That environment is similar to the classical environment `{tabular}` (as provided by `array`) but creates PGF/TikZ nodes under the cells, rows and columns. Then it's possible to use these nodes with TikZ to draw whatever rule you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccc}
  content & content & content & content & content \\
  content & content & content & content & content \\
  content & content & content & content & content \\
  content & content & content & content & content \\
  content & content & content & content & content \\
\CodeAfter
  \tikz \draw (1-|1) rectangle (last-|last) 
              (2-|2) rectangle (5-|4) 
              ([xshift=2pt]3-|2) rectangle ([xshift=-2pt]4-|4) ; 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]