# Nested boxes in table (article mode)

Tags: tables

Someone gave a solution on a topic:
[Nested boxes around cells in a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290745/nested-boxes-around-cells-in-a-table)

But its solution is in standalone mode. The same can be done in "article" mode.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Very simple ... instead `\documentclass[border=3mm, tikz,preview]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,matrix}` use `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibrary{fit,matrix}`

Answer (score 1):

Very simple ... instead

```
\documentclass[border=3mm, tikz, preview]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{fit, matrix}
```

use

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, matrix}
```

As is said in package abstract:

> A class and package is provided which allows TEX pictures or other TEX
>   code to be compiled standalone or as part of a main document. Special
>   support for pictures with beamer overlays is also provided.
>
> The package is used in the main document and skips extra preambles in
>   sub-files. The class may be used to simplify the preamble in
>   sub-files. By default the preview package is used to display the
>   typeset code without margins.

document class and packages are very handy to write examples as it is done in [my answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290745/nested-boxes-around-cells-in-a-table). It is good idea to become familiar with this package. Is is very useful to draw images in LaTeX which code you later include in your document or include generated images with `includegraphics{...}` . Here, on the site is quite extensively used for this purposes.